# the xml database keeps being created

Tags: c#, xml, database, winforms

at this part I am trying to create a new database to put my info in

the problem is that every time I close the program and reopen it creats a new database I'd like to prevent that from happening

is there is a way to check if XML already exist and if yes  how to read from XML without using the Dataset deceleration line and if no what to do on it

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataRow dr;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    dt.TableName = "Employees";
    dt.Columns.Add("Name");
    dt.Columns.Add("E-Mail");
    dt.Columns.Add("Age");
    dt.Columns.Add("WorkHours");
    dt.Columns.Add("Gender");
    dt.Columns.Add("JobTitle");
    //ba3ml tabel be el  klam da
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
}       

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    dr = ds.Tables["Employees"].NewRow();
    dr["Name"] = textBox1.Text;       
    dr["E-Mail"] = textBox2.Text;
    dr["Age"] = textBox4.Text;
    dr["WorkHours"] = textBox5.Text;
    dr["Gender"] = textBox6.Text;
    dr["JobTitle"] = textBox3.Text;
    ds.Tables["Employees"].Rows.Add(dr);

    using (var sw = new StreamWriter("Data.xml"))
    {
        ds.WriteXml(sw);
        sw.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [File.Exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I suggest you make use of the XDocument or XmlDocument class, both of which are documented on the MSDN website.

The way I have always validated the existence of an xml database is by using System.IO.File.Exists(pathToXml). To use this, however, you do need to first save your xml file. You can do this with either class mentioned above.

Reading from / writing to the xml using XDocument or XmlDocument is also fairly easy and documentation on this can be found on the MSDN website.

XDocument: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx
XmlDocument: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396